# Refactor method reference to support parameter(s)

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I want to generify method reference to trigger methods per type,

I save Map of Function Interfaces by key, the functions will call services method, but I have an issue that I can't define paramater using method reference, e.g.:

```
 private Map<Type, Function<User, Boolean>> functionInterfaces = new HashMap<>();
 {
    functionInterfaces.put(Type.MY_TYPE1, MyService::myTypeMethod1);
    functionInterfaces.put(Type.MY_TYPE2, MyService::myTypeMethod2);
    functionInterfaces.put(Type.MY_TYPE3, MyService::myTypeMethod3);
 }
```

Currently I need to create method per type

```
private boolean myTypeMethod1(Parameters parameters) {
    return myGenericTypeMethod(parameters, Type.MY_TYPE1);
}
private boolean myTypeMethod2(Parameters parameters) {
    return myGenericTypeMethod(parameters, Type.MY_TYPE2);
}
```

I call function using apply:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.get(key).apply(new Parameters.Builder().build());
}
```

Can I refactor code to use single method?

Comment: You're not trying to reinvent (poorly) things provided by the language already, are you? What are you trying to accomplish with this "map of functions"?

Comment: @Kayaman define function to execute per type (not all types)

Comment: You wish to register event listeners?

Comment: So you want to introduce an abstraction layer that allows you to map a "key" to a method? What is the advantage in that? What do you intend to use it for? It's certainly not something I'd recommend architecture-wise.

Comment: What is the signature of e.g. `MyService::myTypeMethod1`?

Comment: @Michael it's declared in question, There's Parameters object which hold executing parameters properties

Comment: @Kayaman I'm afraid it is worse. It is adding things *not* provided by the language ;) What about adding an intermediate object that performs the call, rather than trying to call the method directly, with all the trouble that ensues? I mean, if the parameters are different as well, it adds up.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle can you extend your comment to an answer ?

Comment: @Kayaman I don't want event listener, I want to refactor current code, I responded to suggestion in comment

Comment: @user7294900 you should throw away the code, that would be the best refactoring for it.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Still intermediate object will have to choose method per type, what approach you suggesting instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this

```
functionInterfaces.put(Type.MY_TYPE1, MyService::myTypeMethod1);
```

is that `MyService::myTypeMethod1` is an *instance* method. It must take a `MyService`, because that is the instance to be acted upon. You are trying assign it to `Function<User, Boolean>`, but where is the instance in this case?

I don't know whether it makes sense to because we don't have much context, but changing the declaration to

```
Map<Type, BiFunction<MyService, Parameters, Boolean>> functionInterfaces = ...
```

would at least solve the compiler's problem.

In this case, it acts upon `MyService`, takes a `Parameter` and returns a `Boolean`.

---

Alternatively - and, again, we have limited context - making the `MyService` methods static would be sufficient, but you can only do that if they don't require any state.

Comment: @user7294900 The same way you already are. But you will need to invoke it differently (2 args, not 1)

Comment: If I use Spring service which calls its own methods as `this::myTypeMethod1`, what you would suggest to change?